# Add unlock sound effect

Tags: macos, automator, unlock

Whenever I unlock my macOS machine, I want it to play a sound effect from an mp3 file.

- So I created an automator `.app` to play the sound using `Afplay`
  shell command.
- Tested the app successfully.
- And added that app as a login item under Users & Groups.
- Granted the system permission to access the mp3 location when it prompted me to do so.

However, I fear that it is only being triggered when I do a full logout. Not whenever I unlock the lock screen.

[image]

`Catalina 10.15.6 (19G73)`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'll need to use a **Launch Agent** to *watch* for when the **/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist** *file* is *touched*, as it is when the *lock screen* is *unlocked*, to have something you want to have happen when the *lock screen password unlock* event occurs.

Please read the answer in its entirety before implementing it.

The following was tested and works on a clean install of **macOS Catalina** 10.15.6.

Open **Terminal** and execute the following *commands*:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents
touch com.my.detect.screen.unlocked.plist
open -e com.my.detect.screen.unlocked.plist
```

Copy and paste the *example* **XML** *code*, shown further below, into the opened **com.my.detect.screen.unlocked.plist** *document* and then save and close the *document*.

Back in **Terminal**, execute the following *command*:

```bash
launchctl load com.my.detect.screen.unlocked.plist
```

You can now close **Terminal**, if you wish.

To test, click the **Lock Screen** menu item on the **** menu, then log back in.

---

Example **XML** *code*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.my.detect.screen.unlocked</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/afplay</string>
        <string>/System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityInterface.framework/Versions/A/Resources/lockOpening.aif</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

---

**Notes:**

- The sound file in this *example* **XML** *code* obviously can be changed to whatever you'd like, however, I'd suggest that its *path* is not within default *folders* of the *root* of your **Home** *folder* as there may be an issue accessing it. You'll have to test if it's an issue for you. As an example, in the *root* of my **Home** *folder* I have *folders* I've created that where not originally there, that is where I'd place it.
- This will also trigger when you *log out* as the **/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist** *file* is also *touched* during a *log out*. By *touched*, it means at a minimum the *date/time* of the *file* has changed, not necessarily its contents. (I was not able to trap a change to its contents, if there even was one, in spite of the *date/time* of the *file* having changed.)  There may be other *events* that can cause it to be *touched*, so this is not a perfect solution. I'd still implement it and test it for a while. If you are satisfied, you can leave it in place or remove it as you wish.
- To stop the **/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist** file from being *watched*, and thus the sound no longer being played when the *lock screen* is *unlocked*, you'll need to *unload* the **com.my.detect.screen.unlocked.plist** *file* and then delete it.

  - In **Terminal**:

    ```
    cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents
    launchctl unload com.my.detect.screen.unlocked.plist 
    rm com.my.detect.screen.unlocked.plist
    ```

---

**Alternate Method**

This involves the use of a third-party *application* called [**EventScripts**](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html) which costs $4.99 **USD** on the **US App Store**, however, there is a demo version you can download from the developers website to give a test run to see if you feel it's worth the price.

This *application* sits in the menu bar area with the other menu applets and response to a variety of *events*, the one in particular of this subject is **Screen password unlocked** in which you'd use the **AppleScript** `do shell script` *command* to execute, e.g. `afplay /path/to/filename.mp3`.

<sup>**Note:** I am not affiliated with the developer of **EventScripts**, just a satisfied user of the product.</sup>

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
on run eventArgs
    set thisTrigger to (trigger of eventArgs)
    if thisTrigger is "Screen password unlocked" then
        do shell script "/usr/bin/afplay /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityInterface.framework/Versions/A/Resources/lockOpening.aif"
    end if
end run
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you expect `~/sound_effects` to satisfy "root of my Home folder I have folders I've created that where not originally there"? `$pwd` returns `/Users/layne/sound_effects`

Comment: It looks like you or something you installed created `/System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityInterface.framework` because I don't have it

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax Yes, `~/sound_effects` should be fine. -- RE: "It looks like you or something you installed created `/System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityInterface.framework` because I don't have it" -- As I stated in my answer "The following was tested and works on a clean install of **macOS Catalina** 10.15.6.".  -- `/System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityInterface.framework/Versions/A/Resources/lockOpening.aif` is a part of **macOS** and is the sound that is played when one unlocks the **Lock** in, e.g., **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy**.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax So it has to be on your system too. That said, it is only in the _example_ **XML** _code_ as that is what I use to test the _code_ works as stated and as stated in the **Notes:** section of my answer "The sound file in this _example_ **XML** _code_ obviously can be changed to whatever you'd like ..."

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax I had a typo in one of the **Terminal** _commands_ `mkdir -p cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents` the `cd` should not have been there and the actual _command_ is `mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents`. So you can delete the erroneous `cd` _folder_ that was created within the _root_ of your **Home** _folder_.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax See the **Alternate Method** update I made to my answer at the bottom.

Comment: I did try the first method (caught the cd) this morning. It did not run w the file in `~/sound_effects` and I did not see  `/System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityInterface.framework` with an `ls -la`. Will keep playin around this evening.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax You could try putting the file in `/Users/Shared/...` As to `/System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityInterface.framework` please see my earlier comment on it. That said what happens if in **Terminal** you run the following _command_?  `afplay /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityInterface.framework/Versions/A/Resources/lockOpening.aif` Do you hear the sound or do you get an error message?